# how to find cursor is exit from input field. using javascript

Tags: javascript

Hi

How to find cursor is exit from input field.
After cursor is exit from input field

```
alert("some Text");
```

Comment: Listen for a `blur` event on the field. Also remind me never to go on your site, if simply un-focussing an element will throw popups at me.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery:

```
$("#target").blur(function() {
    alert("some text");
});
```

More info here: http://api.jquery.com/blur/

Otherwise:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function lostFocus() {
    alert("some text");
}
</script>

<input type="text" id="target" onblur="lostFocus();">
```

Comment: -1 Question does not include jQuery tag nor any mention of the use of jQuery.

Comment: Great, thanks for downvoting even though it's a valid answer to the question.

Comment: You're welcome. This is *not* a valid answer because it *exclusively* lists an external library which is *not* mentioned in the question in any way. Therefore, it *does not* answer the question.

Comment: It does answer the question, and provides a link to the documentation for said library. The question doesn't specifically say no jQuery, it just says javascript. jQuery IS javascript. :)